# How to copy multiple rows from multiple sheets to paste into one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to paste rows A3:M from XLE, XLF, XLU, XLI, and downwards into the sheet Calendar.

The code below works perfectly for pasting XLE A3:M but I can't figure out how to do the same with the other sheets and append the data at the end of the previous data pasted.

Below is the code:

```
function copyRowsWithSetValues() {
 const id = '113-_bKJT9GkbXBGmB3sOQYhNMrAdQ2xx_oPmAPJrxHA';
 const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);

 const XLE = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('XLE');
 const XLF = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('XLF');
 const XLU = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('XLU');
 const XLI = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('XLI');
 const XLK = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('XLK');
 const XLV = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('XLV');
 const XLY = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('XLY');
 const XLP = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('XLP');
 const XLC = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('XLC');
 const XLB = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('XLB');
 const XLRE = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('XLRE');
 const COUNTRY = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('COUNTRY');
 const Calendar = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Calendar');

 var lastRow = Calendar.getLastRow();
 var lastColumn = Calendar.getLastColumn();

 var range_to_copy = XLE.getRange("A3:M");
 var range_to_paste = Calendar.getRange(lastRow + 1, 2);

 range_to_copy.copyTo(range_to_paste, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT);

}
```

I thought I could copy the data from each sheet using this code: var range_to_copy = XLE.getRange("XLE!A3:M, XLF!A3:M, XLU!A3:M"); and then paste that into the main sheet Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try is this way
    
function copyRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
  const shts = ['XLE','XLF','XLU','XLI','XLK','XLV','XLY','XLP','XLC','XLB','XLRE'];
  const cal = ss.getSheetByName('Calendar');
  shts.forEach((n,i) => {
    let sh = ss.getSheetByName(n);
    let src = sh.getRange("A3:M" + sh.getLastRow());
    let des = cal.getRange(cal.getLastRow() + 1,2);
    src.copyTo(des, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT);
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the error ReferenceError: Cannot access 'src' before initialization